# Set timeout for external API in Promise resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, es6-promise

I have an API that returns some values and depend on that values I want to create an array and pass that array in resolve. It works when set a timeout for resolve, for example, I set `5000 sec` within 5 sec it fetch the data, push array and resolve. But I don't want to set a timeout. Please see the comments for bertter understand. its an nodejs function.

```
const calculateTotal = (arr) => {
  let clientHotspotsTotal = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    arr.forEach((data) => {      
      axios.get(`enpoint/data?.address`)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response?.data) {
            console.log('API SUCCESS');
            const val = (response?.data?.data?.total * data?.percentage) / 100;            
            clientHotspotsTotal.push({
              total: val,
            });
          } else {
            reject('API failed!');
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          throw new Error(error);
        });
    });
    resolve(clientHotspotsTotal);     ///         it return empty [], cause no time set for wait
    setTimeout(() => {
       resolve(clientHotspotsTotal)      //   it doesn't return empty because in that time api fetch data 
                                             an push into array
    }, 5000)
  });
};
```

So my question is how can I wait for that API response for multiple requests as I run a for loop for multiple users.

Comment: You're looking for Promise.all(). Basically: `let clientHotspotsTotal = await Promise.all(arr.map(data => axios.get(...)));` (note that your current code doesn't seem to use the array element anywhere; if you want to insert `data` into the URL you have to actually do that)

Comment: you can resolve the promise inside the then block of the axios request

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this a lot by using *async / await* and Promise.all. We can create an array of promises from the axios calls, then get the response data using Promise.all.

We then iterate through the responses, returning the result.

```
const calculateTotal = async (arr) => {
  const responses = await Promise.all(arr.map(data => axios.get(`enpoint/${data?.address}`)));
  const clientHotspotsTotal = responses.map((response, i) => {
    return({ total: (response?.data?.data?.total * arr[i]?.percentage) / 100});
  });
  return clientHotspotsTotal;
};

async function testIt() {
   let result = await calculateTotal([
     { address: 'someaddress', percentage: 0.50 }, 
     { address: 'someaddress', percentage: 0.75 }
   ]);
   console.log(result);
}

testIt()
```

Comment: `reponses` return undefined!

Comment: ` const clientHotspotsTotal = responses.map((response, i) => {
    return({ total: (response?.data?.data?.total * arr[i]?.percentage) / 100});
  });`

this is not right, in return `arr[i]`,

Comment: Thanks very much for checking out my answer. If the responses are undefined perhaps we're calling the wrong urls? Is `enpoint/${data?.address}` the correct value to pass? That should be easy to change. If responses are undefined, the rest of the code will definitely not work, we'll need to fix that first!

Comment: url is okay even I change it, but it return undefined anyway!

Comment: Thanks for testing! If you log the responses array, is it undefined, or an array of undefined values?

Comment: It works now, Thanks for your time, can explain to me how arr[i]  works inside return, I thought it will not work, since we are not iterate `arr` here!
 `const clientHotspotsTotal = responses.map((response, i) => {
    return({ total: (response?.data?.data?.total * arr[i]?.percentage) / 100});  
  });`

Comment: Sir, I want another help from you. if you want, we can talk on Discord.

Comment: You're very welcome, I am glad to help. The reason arr[i] works is that we are iterating through a promise list of the same length as arr. So arr[i] is the same as data in your first .foreach call.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!